# how many accounts that have never ordered? (in sql)

Tags: mysql, sql

the `product_qty` has the values that explains how many orders an account has made. The task here is to count the number of accounts who never ordered or purchased anything.

| product_qty | account_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1001 |
| 0 | 1002 |
| 5 | 1001 |
| 1 | 1003 |
| 0 | 1002 |
| 9 | 1001 |
| 0 | 1004 |

so far I've been able to write this:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(account_id),
CASE WHEN poster_qty = 0 THEN '0' ELSE 'not 0' END AS poster_qnty
FROM sqlchallenge1.orders 
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1
```

desired output:

| product_qty | account_id_count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 18 | 1 |

Comment: provide data for both of your tables in join.

Comment: *"count the number of accounts who never ordered or purchased anything"* - that does not match your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT product_qty, 
       COUNT(*) account_id_count
FROM (
  SELECT account_id, 
         SUM(product_qty) product_qty
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY account_id
) t
GROUP BY product_qty
ORDER BY product_qty;
```

Or, with `COUNT()` window function if your version of MySql is 8.0+:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       SUM(product_qty) product_qty,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  SUM(product_qty)) account_id_count
FROM orders
GROUP BY account_id
ORDER BY product_qty;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c019712b67190b30343627c83bd06783).